# How to install com ports in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, drivers, dell-inspiron

I'm having a big problem on how to install programs since the ports are not functioning after I just downgraded my laptop's OS to windows 7.

I check my device manager, and I can't find **Universal Serial Bus controllers** and **Ports (COM & LPT)**

Someone knows where can I download a working drivers for this two?

Comment: If your computer is new and came with Windows 10, it may not run Windows 7 properly. That may be why USB is not working.

Comment: Define laptop model. check OEM drivers missing in device mgr and OEM site